# Serialize items in Paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Is there a way to serialize all current items in a project with paper.js? So their positions, styles, etc etc?

Comment: what about creating a javascript model for your app then serialize that model ? if you use the MVC pattern there should not be any problem doing that.

Comment: Can you concretize that, are you experienced with paper.js? I'm adding path's at runtime and want the ability to serialize and deserialize that later without having to much overhead.

Answer (score 5):

When this question was asked, there was no way without diving deep into the structure of the objects and writing your own serializer/deserializer functions.

The paper.js library has since added support for [JSON](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#exportjson).

Answer (score 0):

JSON data format for persistence was implemented as revealed at http://paperjs.org/about/roadmap/

Answer (score -2):

```
var myString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(myObject);
```